# Folder keeps reverting to read-only

Tags: windows-10

Every time I un-check the "read-only" attribute on a folder it automatically reverts the changes I've made.

I tried taking full control of the folder as the administrator and as users and I've also tried using "attrib -r +s drive:\\" in run but it doesnt seem to work.

How can I change the file to read only and keep it from changing back? 
(I'm on windows 10 Home)

Comment: What folder, specifically, are you referring to? Is it perhaps a system folder?

Comment: It's a folder in the F Drive which I use to store data for an accounting software I use. I don't think it's a system folder

Comment: I think that this is simply another case of a classic Windows misunderstanding:  [Rally 'Round the Tri-Mode Flag](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2004/01/01/rally-round-the-trimode-flag.aspx)

Comment: So then how do I fix this "misunderstanding"?

Comment: As the article implies, typically this is a misunderstanding because the folder itself is **not** read-only... one or more files *within* that folder are read-only, instead.

Comment: okay i see that makes sense, so how do i find out which files within the folder are read-only and change them?